# cannon.js basic physics setup as class in three.js

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

Very new to coding and Im following a course on three.js using cannon-es, I have quickly come to understand the need to keep things organized in classes using constructor, (my project is currently all in one or two files and is getting messy.) But still confused as to how to convert existing code into a class. I would like to see an example of basic cannon physics setup as a class or how I can make one.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and was able to make parts as classes but seems buggy as when I add new objects to the Cannon world,the objects before disappear,don't know what causes this but I can share my code with you so we can solve this issue if you are willing.